# Can I pass *array to an EXE?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Is it possible to pass a pointer to an array from my app to a console exe program?

The scenario is: my app needs for certain cases some extra things to be done to the content of the array which is done by the EXE. So if its possible to send a pointer to the EXE and return it after modification ?

Comment: You may want [shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551.aspx).

Comment: How does your .EXE do something on the array ? Does it expect array values on its standard input ? Does it expect a file to contains the data ? Without information on this .EXE we cannot help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To exchange data between separate processes, you need a means of inter-process communication.

Options include:

- shared memory
- pipes
- possibly even sockets

Which of the above is appropriate for you depends on the type and amount of data you want to exchange, how frequently you want to exchange it, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by using the `execv*()` functions to start the new process from the process which provides the array, but are limited to an array of character pointers (`char *`).

Answer (score 0):

No. The parameters given to a new process by the operating systems are an array of strings. You can neither replace that array nor make one of the strings an array.